# Fortran calling a DLL visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, dll, fortran

I've got a Fortran program in which I need to call a routine contained in a C DLL. I've successfully built the DLL and produce the lib file. I've also got the fortran program, but I need to set the Fortran project to read the lib file, how would I go about this?
Thanks,
James

Comment: How are you compiling your Fortran code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Salford SilverFrost compiler. I found the way to do this is to manually edit the References section of the project file. Apparently there's a bug in VS2010 which means you can do this through the menu system.